# Does a derived Dictionary really require the NewItemTypesAttribute to work with the Xceed CollectionEditor?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dictionary, propertygrid, xceed

I am using the `PropertyGrid` control (and by extension the `CollectionEditor`) from the Extended WPF Toolkit 3.0 Community Edition. It does a great job most of the time, but there seems to be a small difference in behavior when having a plain `Dictionary` declared in your class compared to using a custom class that extends `Dictionary`.

Take the following example class:

```
Public Class TestObject
    Public Property MyDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
End Class
```

and this XAML and code-behind to show it in the `PropertyGrid`:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myApp"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <xctk:PropertyGrid x:Name="myPropertyGrid"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Public Class MainWindow
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        myPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = New TestObject()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The result will look like this and everything is fine:
[image: CollectionEditor with EditableKeyValuePair`2]

---

However, if I now change the definition from

```
Public Property MyDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

to

```
Public Property MyDictionary As New DerivedDictionary(Of String, String)
```

where `DerivedDictionary` can be simply declared as

```
Public Class DerivedDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)
    Inherits Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)
End Class
```

then I will no longer get an `` EditableKeyValuePair`2 `` presented in the combobox of the `CollectionEditor`, but instead just a `` KeyValuePair`2 ``, which (as you may have guessed) is not editable. Adding elements to the `DerivedDictionary` from the code-behind will make them show up as `` EditableKeyValuePair`2 `` in the editor as well, so the only problem is the addition of new elements via the UI.

I know that I *could* solve the issue by adding

```
<NewItemTypes(GetType(EditableKeyValuePair(Of String, String)))>
```

to the declaration of `MyDictionary` in `TestObject`. But this seems pretty verbose if I had to do it for every case where a `DerivedDictionary` is used by a class that is meant to be editable via the UI.

Am I missing an easier alternative here? Maybe some attribute that I need to apply to `DerivedDictionary` to make it work? Or is that a bug/limitation in the current `PropertyGrid` control?